# Range.AutoFilter for Filters that may or may not exist

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to solve an issue of creating an Array of Criteria - Some of which may not exist in the column I am looking into. This selection filter if it fails to retrieve one of the filters from the column it will just error out.

I have tried creating an AutoFilter or expression for multiple criteria but this only works for two values.
Creating a dynamic filter of an array supplied with the values that may or may not exist in the given column does not work either.

```
Private Sub HondaSortFilter_Click()
'
' Honda Sort Filter
' This Filter will Filter the PartGroup Column
'
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Civic", "CRV", "Pilot"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Pilot does not exist in the column currently as per Data retrieval has no entries with the supplied string - thusly producing
Error on ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("Civic", "CRV", "Pilot"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

"AutoFilter Method of Range class Failed"

Appreciative of any help!

Comment: You are filtering field 3 in a one column range

Comment: @DarrellH Added the fix Field:=1 - The error is no longer there but It is now not returning any rows due to the "Pilot" Stipulation being in there - Removing pilot provides previous functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that you have to use `Operator:=xlFilterValues` when using an array as your Criteria.

Comment: @GarrettS1 Edited the code to include fix - xlFilterValues, I had done this in my environment but forgot to update. Thanks though that was my previous error !

Comment: Is it possible that your `Selection.AutoFilter` is what is throwing the error? I have used several filters that include criteria that is not present, so I don't know why that wouldn't work. I don't understand what you are trying to use the first auto filter for though...

Comment: @GarrettS1 Okay oddly enough its working now..... No changes were made to the code just re-deleted the line and typed it out - I might have had some syntax issues. The filter is now including the "pilot" string although it may not be present in the column.

Comment: Perfect! Glad to hear it!